# How to check whether a user exists when setting IAM policy in google Big-query?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, email-validation

I'm trying to set IAM policy in google Bigquery using Python. I'm doing it in the following way:

- Get the current policy
- Create a list of new members e.g. ['someone@gmail.com', 'someother@gmail.com', ...]
- Modify the policy by adding the members from the above-created list
- Set policy by calling setIamPolicy method.

The problem with the above approach is that it throws an error `HttpError 400 User ... doesn't exist` when anyone from the members list doesn't exist.

How can I avoid this issue? Is there any API to check whether a user exists or not?

I can also do it using a loop so that if one setIamPolicy call fails(because of user doesn't exits), other memberes still get added but that ends up calling the API multiple times.

Comment: Can you include some code or show us what you're already doing?

Comment: Suggestion: Add people to a Google Group instead. Manage individuals in Google Groups. Then only add to your datasets and IAM policies groups, not individuals.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mapping from emails to users, you can add the following simple python code using boto3 to check if the user exists in aws or not.

```
import boto3
iam = boto3.resource('iam')
user = iam.User('name')
user.load()
```

This will throw a NoSuchEntityException exception if the user doesn't exist.

You can catch the exception and continue if the user doesn't exist. If successful loaded you'll be able to access the users attributes, e.g. user.arn.